# A invisible cookiewhy?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm wanting to get cookies habbo.com.br site that consists of _gads _utma _utmb _utmc _utmt _utmz _ga _gat browser_token session.id and YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666 but when I give comanto alert (document.cooki) returns me all values except browser_token session.id and why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you load a webpage, the web server may decide that to set a cookie as `HttpOnly`. This means that only the web server, when you load new pages, can read that cookie, and that it's inaccessible from any scripts in the browser (including code run from the developer console or the address bar). If you can read the cookie from an extension, but not from a script (such as `alert(document.cookie)`, that seems to be the most likely explanation.

This is most commonly done with session identifying cookies (i.e., those cookies that contain the information necessary to stay logged in). The reason is that if someone were to get these, they could just "copy" them to their own machine and be logged in as you. Thus you typically don't want these cookies to be accessible through scripts, which is a relatively common place to attack visitors of a webpage.

Comment: So there is no way to get?

Comment: @foxtery That's the intention, yes.

Comment: So because I can edit it by the extension manager cookie and it is shown me?

Comment: @foxtery What do you mean?

Comment: Because I is shown by the extension and not the console?

Comment: @foxtery Yes, since extensions typically have more privileges than regular scripts.